# Deep customization of wp-login.php

Tags: customization, login, password, wp-login-form

I'm developing an intranet platform (so no external web access) and using the [Password only login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/password-only-login/) plugin.

I need to make a deep customization to the `wp-login.php` page:

- the plugin i linked allows selected users to login with the password only. To do so it provides the `pol_showform()` function to be put where you want the custom login form (with password only) to appear;
- as not all the user will be allowed to login with password only, i will need to keep the "classic login form". To do so i want to transform the "classic login form" adding a jQuery tab: in the first tab there will be the "password only login" (generated by the `pol_showform()` function), in the second tab there will be the "classic login form".

Now, i searched the web with no success for a way to override the `wp-login.php` page in my child theme. I know it's not a good idea, but it seems the only way to achieve what i need is to edit directly the `wp-login.php` file? Any alternative?

**UPDATE**

Found this [Example2](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_form#Example2) that could solve the situation. The code in the example contains some errors (such as the `echo $our_content` when tha variable is `$your_content`) which is a little bit sad for an official documentation.

Anyway, problem is that there are paragraph added **after** the page has loaded and so the `ob_get_contents()` doesn't capture them. This piece of HTML is composed by the following paragraphs:

```
<p class="forgetmenot">[...]</p>
<p class="submit">[...]</p>
<p id="nav"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function wp_attempt_focus(){
        [...]
    }
</script>
<p id="backtoblog"></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Anyone knows hot to dequee them? Or how to fetch them in the `ob_get_contents()`? Is there any hook that fires after the **whole** page has been cached?

Comment: You'd be better off creating the complete custom login form with shortcode/custom page template at `host/custom-login`, POST to the default login page to handle, and then use the various redirect filters & actions in `wp-login.php` to push back to your page.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic thanks for your suggestion. I found a possible partial solution and updated the question. If you could help me any further.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the login form from your child themes functions.php using actions such as:

```
function my_login_scripts() {
    //do stuff here
}

add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_scripts' );
```

This should at least allow you to get your jQuery running on the page.

You can read more about this here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

Comment: thanks, i've already read that page. I maybe found a system with this [Example2](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_form#Example2). I've updated my question if you could help me any further.